# JSON API: Resource depending on another resource. How to format URL?

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, restful-url, json-api

I've got troubles to understand how to present resources that depend on each other in JSON API.

Consider, we have a resource `Collection` which can have a multiple resources called `List`. A `List` without a `Collection` does not make sense, so I would say a `List` cannot live without a `Collection`. Furthermore, a `List` has multiple resources called `Item` which also need a `List` to exists.

The allocation is fixed. So for example you cannot move a `List` to an other `Collection` or a `Item` to an other `List`. You can only add/delete `Lists` to/from a existing `Collection` or a add/delete `Items` to/from a existing `List`.

The Endpoint for `Collection` would be simply `/api/collection`. A specific `Collection` will be returned by `api/collection/{id}`. 
Since `Collection` has a relationship to `List` there would exist the relationship `related link` according to the JSON API specification `/api/collection/{id}/lists` that represents only the `List` resources that are connected to the `Collection` resource with the id specified in the URL.

But what is the best was to make the rest of the api?

- Possibility 1:

I do a endpoint `/api/lists` and `api/lists/{id}` to link to the `List` resources. The same goes for the resource `Item`. `/api/items` and `/api/items/{id}`.

The good thing about this approach is that I can do "clean" relationship `related link` like `api/lists/{id}/items` and `api/lists/{id}/collection`.

The bad thing is that I don't know what to return on `/api/lists` and `/api/items` since they cannot really exist without their parent element. Should I return error code 403 or just all Lists and Items? Both is ugly.

POSTing new resources would be work for example on `/api/items` AND `api/lists/{id}/items`. But in the first case you have to include the relationship to the `List` resource in the POST-body because you cannot determine it by the URL.

- Possibility 2:

For `List` I provide a endpoint like `api/collection/{id}/lists` and `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}`. For `Item` I provide `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items` and `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}`.

The good thing is that I have a clear mapping of which resource belongs to which other resource.

The bad thing is that the URL are getting longer and longer.
An other point are the `related links` for relationships. For example I want to link from a `Item` to its `List`. The URL would be: `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}/list`.

(Even worse would be the `self link` of the relationship: `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}/relationships/list`. But I don't think that this will be a problem, because the `self` link is optional. I also think that I don't need the `self` link of the relationship because as I said before the allocation is fixed. You cannot assign a `List` to another `Collection` or assign a `Item` to a second `List`. So I don't need to change the connections between the relationships and therefore I don't need the `self link` to do so.)

Another option to format the `related link` would be `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}`. But this is the same link as for the resource `List` with {id}. Is this valid to JSON API spec? Since the allocation is fixed that would make sense, However, this also feels a bit ugly, too.

What would you do? What do you think is better and more Restful and more JSON API compliant?

Comment: With JSON API do you mean jsonapi.org ? If so a `relationship` attribute is mandatory as far as I understand it. But *only* the relationship would be `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}/relationships/list` the list itself could be (or probably should be) at `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}`. Also if the consumer of your api are programs long urls don't really matter (it is far more important that the api is clear).

Comment: Yes, I mean jsonapi.org/.

But the point is that `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}/relationships/list` and `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}` will exactly return the same. Always! Because of the fixed (logial) allocation. POST, PUT and DELETE on `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}/relationships/list` will always be error code 403 since changing is of the relationships is not allowed by the server and its logical application. So `api/collection/{id}/lists/{id}/items/{id}/relationships/list`  makes more or less no sense.